# Parallel TestNG - cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.hooks.CustomHook' available

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, hook

I have my testng.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="BDD Test Suite" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="1" configfailurepolicy="continue">
    <test name="Test 1" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="CukesTestRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test 2" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="CukesTestRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

It is running fine when thread-count="1", so it runs the same tests on Chrome and Firefox one by one sequentially. But when switching to 2 thread-count, in order to run them simultaneously on 2 browsers, I have got this error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.hooks.CustomHook' available: expected single matching bean but found 1: com.hooks.CustomHook
```

It looks like the cucumber `glue` does not work with multithreading anymore. It is wired up like:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "classpath:features",
    plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report" , "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json"},
    glue = { "com.hooks", "com.stepdef" },
    tags = {"@run"}
)
public class CukesTestRunner {
...
```

My guess is a thead already took it so the other complains, but I am not sure whether any config is missing for running TestNG in parallel. Or is there another approach to achieve running tests on 2 browsers concurrently? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you using spring for DI?

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure about your Bean related error, but possibly passing 'Parallel' and 'Thread-count' tags at test level also [see below] will trigger Two browsers in Parallel..

> 

```
<test name= "My Regression-Test1" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.abb.www.grid.runnerClasses1"/>
        <class name="com.abb.www.grid.runnerClasses2"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

....so on...